# How to create editable cart items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, shopping-cart, javascript-objects

I'm building a shopping cart.  My `display object` below is the data available to the shopper.  The `cart object` is the representation of the shoppers selection in the cart.  The problem I'm having is, say someone wants to edit the item in the cart and change it's size.  The `sizes` aren't available in the cart item anymore cause I've already selected a size & killed the rest.

```
// display object
{
    "sizes": [
        {
            "price": 4.99,
            "title": "s"
        },
        {
            "price": 5.99,
            "title": "m"
        },
        {
            "price": 6.99,
            "title": "l"
        }
    ],
    "desc": "here's our green hat",
    "title": "green hat"
}

// cart object
{
    "size": 
    {
        "price": 4.99,
        "title": "s"
    },
    "desc": "here's our green hat",
    "title": "green hat"
}
```

SO....should I just pass along my whole `display object` & be marking (somehow) which option has been selected? Or is there another solution I'm missing?

Comment: You could end up with a lot of redundant information by having all the possible options included with every object.  Why not keep the info about your objects in an angular service (that can pulled from a DB or some kind of backend).  And then a way to get the info about your object and set it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

In case your shopping items are frequently changeable you have to bring again from your backend system to make sure your data is consistent. at this time better to make a call to database and fetch the whole object with all sizes. this solution also is better for bringing the current states of your items (may be size L was available but now it is not after deciding to change as it is having a lot of traffic in purchases)

**Hint:** you could allow your backend system to cache the items that are frequently called with their sizes for better performance results.

But in case your shopping items are not usually changeable or updatable, it would be better to pass the whole object with all sizes with addition to the new property to identify the selected one.

Comment: Right, but is there a better way to organize my model so that it would be easier to comb through to repopulate the new form with their previous input?